# Rails and wmd-new editor, posted data from the textarea has html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Little confused with using the wmw-new editor with my rails 3 app.

The posted data from the textarea has HTML in it, shouldn't it have the markdown markup that I would then have to parse?

I tried html decoding it and it looks like a mess.

Comment: You can escape the characters in your form, but then when you update it doesn't keep the tags. This is why I stopped using WMD

Comment: are you including bluecloth or RDiscount in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

To help the next person that looks this way, you can set this as an option in js:

```
wmd_options = {
    output: "Markdown"
};
```

Or if that doesn't work, you can edit the source (wmd.js) to set the default by changing this line:

```
Attacklab.wmd_defaults = {version:1, output:"HTML", lineLength:40, delayLoad:false};
```

to

```
Attacklab.wmd_defaults = {version:1, output:"Markdown", lineLength:40, delayLoad:false};
```